# How to test an empty variable?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a textbox in VisualForce [UserDate1],

That I use for input for the next step,

When I print out the variable value UserDate1 without entering the date,

The log does not print anything [empty string]

And when I do, the log prints out the date I have entered,

Of course everything is fine at this point,

How do I test the UserDate1 variable for empty strings?

A sample of the code is below

```
public with sharing class Best_practice {

    public PageReference download_csv() {
      system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,UserDate1 );

        return null;
    }


    public String USerInput { get; set; }

    public String USerDate1 { get; set; }
}

<apex:page Controller="Best_practice" tabStyle="Opportunity" >
<apex:sectionHeader title="Choose Action"/>
<apex:pagemessages /> 
<apex:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <apex:pageBlock >
 <apex:actionRegion >
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Enter Maximum date for all actions">  
         <apex:panelGrid columns="3">
             <apex:outputLabel value="Enter Date"/>
             <apex:inputText id="inqueryDateAdd" value="{!USerDate1}" required="false"/>
             <apex:outputLabel value="YYYY-MM-DD"/>
         </apex:panelGrid>
     </apex:pageBlockSection>
     <apex:pageBlockSection title="Obtain user information for new inquiries">  
         <apex:panelGrid columns="4">
            <apex:outputLabel value="Enter email"/>
             <apex:inputText id="inqueryEmailAdd" value="{!USerInput}" required="false"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!download_csv}" value="Send" styleClass="btn" />
            <apex:outputLabel value="This button will send all the new trainees to the email entered"/>
         </apex:panelGrid>
     </apex:pageBlockSection>
     </apex:actionRegion>


     </apex:pageBlock> 

    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public PageReference download_csv() {
    system.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,UserDate1 );
    if(String.IsBlank(UserDate1){
        //field is blank
    }
    return null;
}
```